# Handling user signup, catch errors firebase stopping user from accessing the site if errors

Tags: firebase, webflow

so I'm building a website with Webflow and Google services ie Firebase. At the moment the website can signup, log out, and sign in my users, It just takes them to a blank dashboard.

My problem is I would like all users that get redirected to the dashboard to have their displayname by updateProfile and Database user/id table filled in but if either of them throws a catch error the account was still created and this would allow a user to sign in without all the information I may need of the user on the dashboard. Is there a better way to do this other than checking on signup if the user's data is available? I wish I could just create a user Update DisplayName & submit their data to the database at once and if any of this fails the user account is not created as it would cause hassle.

My code below

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-auth.js";
import { getDatabase, ref, set  } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.22.0/firebase-database.js';
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {//Hidden};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//Creating auth variable
const auth = getAuth();

// Initialize Realtime Database and get a reference to the service
const database = getDatabase(app);

// CUSTOM VAR'S, First name is gathered when signup button is click and is saved here for uploading to the realtime database
// When the save button function is called
var firstNameGlobal;
var inSignupProgress = false;

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user && inSignupProgress) {
      // Show nav links
      navLinkHome.style.display = 'inline-block';
      navLinkLogin.style.display = 'inline-block';
      navLinkSignup.style.display = 'inline-block';
    } else if (user && !inSignupProgress) {
      // User is logged in and is not in signup process so redirecting
      window.location.replace('./dashboard');
    } else {
      //Show nav links
      navLinkHome.style.display = 'inline-block';
      navLinkLogin.style.display = 'inline-block';
      navLinkSignup.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
});
  
// On click, regester the user, update there profile, DisplayName, and show form two
buttonSignup.addEventListener('click', function() {
  
    // getting data from the email and password fields
    const firstName = document.getElementById('inputFirstName').value; //Set firstname globaly so i can use it outside this function
    firstNameGlobal = firstName;

    const email = document.getElementById('inputEmail').value;
    const password = document.getElementById('signupPassword').value;
    const passwordConfirm = document.getElementById('signupPasswordConfirm').value;

    // Check if user entered passwords are the same
    if (password === passwordConfirm) {

      // Set inSignupProgress to true
      inSignupProgress = true;

      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;

        // Signup successfull
        console.log("Signup successfull");
    
        // Update users displayName
        updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
          displayName: firstName }).then(() => {
          // Profile updated!
          console.log("Profile Updated")

          // Remove form one and show form two
          document.getElementById('spFormOne').style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById('spFormTwo').style.display = "block";

        }).catch((error) => {
          
          // An error occurred
          console.log(error)
          formOneError.innerText = "Account was created but there was an error, please contact support. Error: " + error;
          formOneError.style.display = 'block';

          // Signout user now that Update Profile failed
          signOut(auth).then(() => {
            // Sign-out successful.
          }).catch((error) => {
            // TODO make this error more usfull to the user
            alert ("Hello there has been a error signing you out :( and updating you profile please contact support so I can fix this. Error: \n" + error);
            console.log("Error: " + error);
          });

        });
        
      }).catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
    
        //Log error messages
        console.log("ErrorCode signup not successfull: " + errorCode);
    
        //Show error text and edit its text
        formOneError.innerText = errorMessage;
        formOneError.style.display = 'block';
      });

    } else {
      //Tell user passwords dont match
      formOneError.innerText = "Opps, passwords dont match.";
      formOneError.style.display = 'block';
    }
  
});

buttonSave.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  
  // Get value from dob field
  var dobInput = document.getElementById('inputDOB').value;

  // Bot wrote this shit but will only let right dd-mm-yyyy formate for dob through
  var dobPattern = /^(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}$/;
  if (!dobPattern.test(dobInput)) {
    // Invalid DOB format Show error message

    // Log error
    console.log("Please enter a valid DOB in the format DD-MM-YYYY");
    
    //Show user the error
    document.getElementById('formTwoError').innerText = "Please enter a valid DOB in the format DD-MM-YYYY";
    document.getElementById('formTwoError').style.display = "block";

  } else {
  
    // this code makes sure the date of birth is not in the future
    var dobParts = dobInput.split("-");
    var inputDate = new Date(dobParts[2], dobParts[1] - 1, dobParts[0]);
    var currentDate = new Date();

    if (inputDate > currentDate) {

      // DOB is in the future
      document.getElementById('formTwoError').innerText = "Date of birth cannot be in the future";
      document.getElementById('formTwoError').style.display = "block";

    } else {
      // Valid DOB
      //Get the country varibale
      var countrySelect = document.getElementById('countrySelect').value;
      
      // Check to see if country selected
      if (countrySelect !== "none") {

        // Send data to the database
        set(ref(database, `users/${auth.currentUser.uid}`), {
          firstName: firstNameGlobal,
          Dob: dobInput,
          Country: countrySelect,
          signupComplete: true,
        }).then(() => {
          // Data sent successfully
          // Send user to the dashbaord
          window.location.replace('./dashboard');

        }).catch((error) => {
          // Error with sending data to the database
          console.log("Error uploading data:\n" + error);

          // TODO make this error more usfull to the user
          document.getElementById('formTwoError').innerText = error + " Please contact support";
          document.getElementById('formTwoError').style.display = "block";
        });
        
      } else {
        // Log and tell user the error
        console.log("Country not selected");
        document.getElementById('formTwoError').innerText = "Country not selected";
        document.getElementById('formTwoError').style.display = "block";
      }

    }
  }
  
});

function deleteUser() {

}
```

I thought if either updateProfile or Uploading there data to the database fails I can just use auth to immediately delete the user. I could check to see if users have that data on login but I fear this would be extra database communication I don't need. Thank you for :)